# AdbCommandRejectedException is received when app is run on 4.x OS versions for Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on an application in which I had to update my adt plugin and Android SDK. Since when i have updated these, Android OS versions 4.x are creating problems. I  run the application on 2.1 to 2.3.3 and emulator launches fine and app runs. It runs on device as well. But when try to run the app on 4.0.2 or 4.0.3 emulator starts and then it disappears from from the device list in eclipse. But emulator is available in my taskbar. I check log and see the following error. This comes with 4.x OS versions. I haven't tried it on 3.x. What can be the problem?

```
[2012-01-10 10:11:18 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the   device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:372)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:100)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Sometime i kill the adb server 2 or 3 times and emulator starts and then problem disappears. But every new day i come to work and face the same issue for 4.x OS versions.

Can somebody point out the actual reason behind? Same ADT plugin and SDK works absolutely fine for devices and emulators with  2.x OS versions but fails for 4.x version. Please get me out of this. Any helps is appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed the while Android 4 package.
Go to Eclipse -> Window -> Android SDK Manager, and install Google APIs (and Samples for SDK).
Restart Eclipse, and your LogCat will function with Android 4.

Regards,
Natasha